# Translation of "scholie".

Tags: mathematical-french

What is a good translation for the word "scholie"? This appears in Grothendieck, EGA III 5.1.7, and I don't know its meaning. Neither DeepL nor Google translate nor dict.leo.org know this word.

It does not appear in a sentence, but at the beginning of a paragraph, like "Lemme", "Corollaire" or "Remarque".

Comment: It might help to include it in a sentence.

Comment: Maybe [scholia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholia#Other_uses): marginal notes which may amplify a line of reasoning or compare it with proofs given earlierz.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Unfortunately it is not part of a sentence, but appears at the beginning of a paragraph like "Remarque".

Comment: A scholium is a remark. Scholia probably refers to remarks concerning the previous paragraph. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261036/what-is-a-scholium) for a discussion of this.

Comment: Famous example [Newton's General Scholium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Scholium)

Comment: It is a comment. From the Greek  `σχολιον`.

Comment: [What Mauro ALLEGRANZA says](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholie), but in French, in which language I believe EGA was written.